# How to make a c++ program that finds number's digits square value

Tags: c++

I need help creating a c++ program.

Create a program that finds the sum of the squares of digits of a given number.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, p, sum;
    cout << "enter your number" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        p = n % 10; 
        sum = p + n; 
        n = n / 10; // 
    }
    cout << "square : " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know how to finish it.

For example, if I enter number `222`, the answer should be `12` because:

```
(2*2)+(2*2)+(2*2) = 12
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service

Comment: Begin by thinking about how you would do this with pencil and paper. Once you understand that, start to write code.

Comment: Start by figuring out how to extract the individual digits of a number. Then find out how to square a number. Then combine the previous two steps to square each digit of the number.

Comment: You're asking a question without first learning *how*. Read the [help] and the [ask] please.

Comment: OK, you've posted code, now please explain what it does, what it doesn't do, what your *specific* problem is. This isn't a "please finish my code for me" site, but rather a Q and A site. Again please read the [ask] to learn site best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo in the line:

`sum = p + n;`

change it to  `sum += (p*p);`. It will work.

**A small tip**: This kind of mistakes can be easily catched using the debugger. Therefore, strongly suggest learning using it.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @latesttech Your welcome :)